# Android program crashing

Tags: android, debugging, crash, fragment

My app works fine normally, but if it runs in the background for a while or a Task Killer is used it crashes on startup if left off on a certain fragment, which in my program is called infofragment. Here is the logcat info for each crash:

```
02-25 21:12:23.546: E/AndroidRuntime(20048): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 21:12:23.546: E/AndroidRuntime(20048): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.fragments/com.example.android.fragments.MainActivity}: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.android.fragments.InfoFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
02-25 21:12:23.546: E/AndroidRuntime(20048):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2088)
02-25 21:12:23.546: E/AndroidRuntime(20048):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113)
02-25 21:12:23.546: E/AndroidRuntime(20048):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139)
02-25 21:12:23.546: E/AndroidRuntime(20048):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1224)
02-25 21:12:23.546: E/AndroidRuntime(20048):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-25 21:12:23.546: E/AndroidRuntime(20048):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-25 21:12:23.546: E/AndroidRuntime(20048):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
02-25 21:12:23.546: E/AndroidRuntime(20048):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 21:12:23.546: E/AndroidRuntime(20048):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-25 21:12:23.546: E/AndroidRuntime(20048):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
02-25 21:12:23.546: E/AndroidRuntime(20048):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
02-25 21:12:23.546: E/AndroidRuntime(20048):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-25 21:12:23.546: E/AndroidRuntime(20048): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.android.fragments.InfoFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
02-25 21:12:23.546: E/AndroidRuntime(20048):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:395)
02-25 21:12:23.546: E/AndroidRuntime(20048):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:96)
02-25 21:12:23.546: E/AndroidRuntime(20048):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1726)
02-25 21:12:23.546: E/AndroidRuntime(20048):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:198)
02-25 21:12:23.546: E/AndroidRuntime(20048):    at com.example.android.fragments.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
02-25 21:12:23.546: E/AndroidRuntime(20048):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5048)
02-25 21:12:23.546: E/AndroidRuntime(20048):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
02-25 21:12:23.546: E/AndroidRuntime(20048):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2052)
02-25 21:12:23.546: E/AndroidRuntime(20048):    ... 11 more
02-25 21:12:23.546: E/AndroidRuntime(20048): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.android.fragments.InfoFragment; no empty constructor
02-25 21:12:23.546: E/AndroidRuntime(20048):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
02-25 21:12:23.546: E/AndroidRuntime(20048):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
02-25 21:12:23.546: E/AndroidRuntime(20048):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:384)
02-25 21:12:23.546: E/AndroidRuntime(20048):    ... 18 more
```

The only thing I see it pointing to is the super.onCreate() in the onCreate() function of the main activity. Here is the code for the main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity 
        implements MainListFragment.OnListSelectedListener {

    MainListFragment tempmainfrag;
    InfoFragment infofrag;
    int mainPosition = -1;
    MenuItem menuItemAdd;   //plus button in ActionBar/options menu
    boolean menucreated = false;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);

        // Check whether the activity is using the layout version with
        // the fragment_container FrameLayout. If so, we must add the first fragment
        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) { //meaning, if using phone version


            // Create an instance of MainListFragment
            tempmainfrag = new MainListFragment();  //made a context parameter to pass the context

            // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an Intent,
            // pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
            tempmainfrag.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());



            // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, tempmainfrag).commit();

            Log.i("mydebug","TEMPMAINFRAG: " + tempmainfrag);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {       
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {

        Log.i("mydebug","1");
        if(menuItemAdd != null)     
            menuItemAdd.setVisible(true);   //turns on menu item 'add'

        super.onStart();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        menuItemAdd = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_add);
        menucreated = true;

        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_add:     //NEED TO IMPLEMENT: MAKES ICON PRESS FOR BACK GO BACK
                // Create fragment
                infofrag = new InfoFragment(menuItemAdd);
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putBoolean(infofrag.ARG_NEW, true);

                infofrag.setArguments(args);

                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
                // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, infofrag);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                // Commit the transaction
                transaction.commit();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void onItemSelected(int position, String schedulename, String[] ampm, boolean[] days, int[] times, boolean vibrate) {
        // The user selected a list item

        //////////////////////////////TWO PANE LAYOUT STUFF///////////////////////////////////
        // Capture the article fragment from the activity layout
//        InfoFragment articleFrag = (InfoFragment)
//                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);  //article_fragment exists in layout-large
//
//        if (articleFrag != null) {
//            // If article frag is available, we're in two-pane layout...
//
//            // Call a method in the ArticleFragment to update its content
//            articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);
//
//        } else {
            // phone layout - swap frags

            mainPosition = position;

            // Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article
            infofrag = new InfoFragment(menuItemAdd);
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(infofrag.ARG_POSITION, position);

            //new stuff to add info
            args.putString(infofrag.ARG_NAME, schedulename);    
            args.putBooleanArray(infofrag.ARG_DAYS, days);
            args.putIntArray(infofrag.ARG_TIMES, times);
            args.putBoolean(infofrag.ARG_VIBRATE, vibrate); 
            args.putStringArray(infofrag.ARG_AMPM, ampm);
            args.putBoolean(infofrag.ARG_NEW, false);

            infofrag.setArguments(args);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
            // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, infofrag);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();

    }

    public void saveButtonClicked(View view) {  //pass the click to the mainlistfragment
//      MainListFragment tempmainfrag2 = (MainListFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().
//                findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

        Log.i("mydebug","TEMPMAINFRAG: " + tempmainfrag);
        if(!infofrag.newsched)  //if existing schedule, so save
        {
            Log.i("mydebug","Saving schedule...");
            boolean redo = false;       //is set true every time info isnt correct when trying to save schedule
            //create toast
            Toast toast;

            //get title
            EditText titletext = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.titletext);

            //get checkboxes
            CheckBox check1 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.monbox); //recreate checkboxes from view in activity (doesnt extend Activity 
            CheckBox check2 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.tuebox); //so use getActivity())
            CheckBox check3 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.wedbox);
            CheckBox check4 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.thubox);
            CheckBox check5 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.fribox);
            CheckBox check6 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.satbox);
            CheckBox check7 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.sunbox);
            CheckBox vibratebox = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.vibratecheckbox);

            //get times
            TimePicker startpicker = (TimePicker)this.findViewById(R.id.starttimepicker);
            TimePicker stoppicker = (TimePicker)this.findViewById(R.id.stoptimepicker);

            //check for input errors
            if(titletext.getText().toString().length() == 0) //if title is empty
            {
                redo = true;
                toast = Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Enter an event name", 4);
                toast.show();

                //some sick-ass shake animations!!!
                Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(titletext.getContext(), R.anim.shake_big);
                this.findViewById(R.id.titletext).startAnimation(shake);
            }
            else if((!check1.isChecked()) && (!check2.isChecked()) && (!check3.isChecked()) && 
                    (!check4.isChecked()) && (!check5.isChecked()) && (!check6.isChecked()) && 
                    (!check7.isChecked()))  //if all checkboxes arent checked
            {
                redo = true;
                toast = Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "At least one day of week must be checked", 4);
                toast.show();

                //more sick-ass shake animations!!!
                Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(titletext.getContext(), R.anim.shake_small);
                this.findViewById(R.id.checkboxes).startAnimation(shake);
                this.findViewById(R.id.daysofweek).startAnimation(shake);
                this.findViewById(R.id.frequencytext).startAnimation(shake);
            }

            if(!redo)   //if all info is fine
            {
                //check to see if time goes into next day
                if((startpicker.getCurrentHour() > stoppicker.getCurrentHour())||
                        ((startpicker.getCurrentHour() == stoppicker.getCurrentHour())
                                && (startpicker.getCurrentMinute() >= stoppicker.getCurrentMinute())))
                {
                    toast = Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Note: Stop time is earlier than start time, so this schedule stops at next day", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }

                toast = Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Schedule saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();

                //changing old schedule to new one
                boolean[] tempdays = {check1.isChecked(), check2.isChecked(), check3.isChecked(), check4.isChecked(), 
                        check5.isChecked(), check6.isChecked(), check7.isChecked()};

                Log.i("mydebug","Time info read from counters: Start hour: " + startpicker.getCurrentHour() + "\nStop hour: " + stoppicker.getCurrentHour());

                tempmainfrag.mainObjectList.changeSchedule(mainPosition, titletext.getText().toString(), tempdays, vibratebox.isChecked(), 
                        startpicker.getCurrentHour(), startpicker.getCurrentMinute(), stoppicker.getCurrentHour(), stoppicker.getCurrentMinute());

                //used to hide keyboard in case its still open when displaying list
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(
                          Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(titletext.getWindowToken(), 0);

                this.onBackPressed();   //replicates backpress to go back to list
            }
        }
        else        //if new schedule needs to be created
        {
            Log.i("mydebug","Creating new schedule...");
            boolean redo = false;
            //create toast
            Toast toast;

            //get title
            EditText titletext = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.titletext);

            //get checkboxes
            CheckBox check1 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.monbox); //recreate checkboxes from view in activity (doesnt extend Activity 
            CheckBox check2 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.tuebox); //so use getActivity())
            CheckBox check3 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.wedbox);
            CheckBox check4 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.thubox);
            CheckBox check5 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.fribox);
            CheckBox check6 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.satbox);
            CheckBox check7 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.sunbox);
            CheckBox vibratebox = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.vibratecheckbox);

            //get times
            TimePicker startpicker = (TimePicker)this.findViewById(R.id.starttimepicker);
            TimePicker stoppicker = (TimePicker)this.findViewById(R.id.stoptimepicker);

            EditText temppp = titletext;
            //check for input errors
            if(titletext.getText().toString().length() == 0) //if title is empty
            {
                redo = true;
                toast = Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Enter an event name", 4);
                toast.show();

                //some sick-ass shake animations!!!
                Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(titletext.getContext(), R.anim.shake_big);
                this.findViewById(R.id.titletext).startAnimation(shake);
            }
            else if((!check1.isChecked()) && (!check2.isChecked()) && (!check3.isChecked()) && 
                    (!check4.isChecked()) && (!check5.isChecked()) && (!check6.isChecked()) && 
                    (!check7.isChecked()))  //if all checkboxes arent checked
            {
                redo = true;
                toast = Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "At least one day of week must be checked", 4);
                toast.show();

                //more sick-ass shake animations!!!
                Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(titletext.getContext(), R.anim.shake_small);
                this.findViewById(R.id.checkboxes).startAnimation(shake);
                this.findViewById(R.id.daysofweek).startAnimation(shake);
                this.findViewById(R.id.frequencytext).startAnimation(shake);
            }

            if(!redo)   //if all info is fine
            {
                //check to see if time goes into next day
                if((startpicker.getCurrentHour() > stoppicker.getCurrentHour())||
                        ((startpicker.getCurrentHour() == stoppicker.getCurrentHour())
                                && (startpicker.getCurrentMinute() >= stoppicker.getCurrentMinute())))
                {
                    toast = Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Note: Stop time is earlier than start time, so this schedule stops at next day", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }

                toast = Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Schedule created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();

                //changing old schedule to new one
                boolean[] tempdays = {check1.isChecked(), check2.isChecked(), check3.isChecked(), check4.isChecked(), 
                        check5.isChecked(), check6.isChecked(), check7.isChecked()};

                Log.i("mydebug","Time info read from counters: Start hour: " + startpicker.getCurrentHour() + "\nStop hour: " + stoppicker.getCurrentHour());

                tempmainfrag.mainObjectList.addSchedule(titletext.getText().toString(), tempdays, vibratebox.isChecked(), 
                        startpicker.getCurrentHour(), startpicker.getCurrentMinute(), stoppicker.getCurrentHour(), stoppicker.getCurrentMinute());

                //used to hide keyboard in case its still open when displaying list
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(
                          Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(titletext.getWindowToken(), 0);

                this.onBackPressed();   //replicates backpress to go back to list
            }
        }
    }

    public void deleteButtonClicked(View view)
    {
        //tempmainfrag = (MainListFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().
                //findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

        if(!infofrag.newsched)  //if existing schedule, so ask to delete
        {
            //make a notification

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Delete?");
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.trash_icon);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you wish to delete this schedule?")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       tempmainfrag.mainObjectList.removeSchedule(mainPosition);

                       Toast toast;
                       toast = Toast.makeText(tempmainfrag.getActivity(), "Schedule deleted", 4);
                        toast.show();

                       tempmainfrag.exit();
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                   }
               });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
        else    //if new schedule, so just cancel
            tempmainfrag.exit();
    }

    public void hideKeyboard()  //hides keyboard, called whenever reverting back to list
    {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
                  Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the fragment that makes the app crash if last left open and a task killer is used:

```
public class InfoFragment extends Fragment {
    //strings used to get info from MainListFragment
    public String ARG_POSITION = "position";
    public String ARG_NAME = "name";
    public String ARG_DAYS = "days";
    public String ARG_TIMES = "times";
    public String ARG_VIBRATE = "vibrate";
    public String ARG_AMPM = "ampm";
    public String ARG_NEW = "new";

    boolean newsched = false;
    int mCurrentPosition = -1;
    MenuItem menuItemAddInfo;

    public InfoFragment(MenuItem add)
    {
        menuItemAddInfo = add;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // If activity recreated (such as from screen rotate), restore
        // the previous article selection set by onSaveInstanceState().
        // This is primarily necessary when in the two-pane layout.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(ARG_POSITION);
        }

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.infolayout, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {

        super.onStart();
        menuItemAddInfo.setVisible(false);

        // During startup, check if there are arguments passed to the fragment.
        // onStart is a good place to do this because the layout has already been
        // applied to the fragment at this point so we can safely call the method
        // below that sets the article text.
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (!args.getBoolean(ARG_NEW)) //if creating fragment with existing info i.e. not new schedule
        {
            newsched = false;
            Log.i("mydebug", "TYPE: Existing schedule");
            // if a list item is clicked and arguments are fed in
            updateInfoView(args.getInt(ARG_POSITION), args.getString(ARG_NAME), args.getStringArray(ARG_AMPM), args.getBooleanArray(ARG_DAYS), 
                    args.getIntArray(ARG_TIMES), args.getBoolean(ARG_VIBRATE));
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i("mydebug", "TYPE: New schedule");
            Button changesave = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.savebutton);
            changesave.setText("Create");
            Button changedelete = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.cancelbutton);
            changedelete.setText("Cancel");
            newsched = true;

            //set defaults
            TimePicker startpicker = (TimePicker)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.starttimepicker);
            TimePicker stoppicker = (TimePicker)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.stoptimepicker);
            startpicker.setCurrentHour(8);
            startpicker.setCurrentMinute(0);
            stoppicker.setCurrentHour(15);
            stoppicker.setCurrentMinute(0);
            CheckBox vibratebox = (CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.vibratecheckbox);
            vibratebox.setChecked(true);
        }
        //set up custom font
        Typeface customfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");

        TextView frequency = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.frequencytext);
        TextView start = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.starttext);
        TextView stop = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.stoptext);
        CheckBox vibratebox = (CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.vibratecheckbox);
        TextView mon = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.montext);
        TextView tue = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tuetext);
        TextView wed = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.wedtext);
        TextView thu = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.thutext);
        TextView fri = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fritext);
        TextView sat = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sattext);
        TextView sun = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.suntext);
        EditText title = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.titletext);

        frequency.setTypeface(customfont);
        start.setTypeface(customfont);
        stop.setTypeface(customfont);
        vibratebox.setTypeface(customfont);
        mon.setTypeface(customfont);
        tue.setTypeface(customfont);
        wed.setTypeface(customfont);
        thu.setTypeface(customfont);
        fri.setTypeface(customfont);
        sat.setTypeface(customfont);
        sun.setTypeface(customfont);
        title.setTypeface(customfont);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop()
    {
        if(menuItemAddInfo != null)     
            menuItemAddInfo.setVisible(true);   //turns on menu item 'add'
        super.onStop();
    }
    public void updateInfoView(int position, String schedulename, String[] ampm,  boolean[] days, int[] times, boolean vibrate) {   //previously used to set which article

        mCurrentPosition = position;
        //debugging info
        String debugdays = String.valueOf(days[0]) + ", " + String.valueOf(days[1]) + ", " + String.valueOf(days[2]) + ", " + 
                String.valueOf(days[3]) + ", " + String.valueOf(days[4]) + ", " + String.valueOf(days[5]) + ", " + String.valueOf(days[6]);
        String debug = "LISTITEMCLICKED:\nPosition:" + position + "\nName:" + schedulename + "\nStart AM/PM:" + ampm[0] + "\nStop AM/PM:" + ampm[1]
                + "\nDays:" + debugdays + "\nStart time: " + times[0] + ":" + times[1] + "\nStop time: " + times[2] + ":" + times[3] + "\nVibrate: " + vibrate;
        Log.i("mydebug",debug);


        //set title
        EditText titletext = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.titletext);
        titletext.setText(schedulename);
        titletext.setSelection(titletext.getText().length());   //just sets cursor at end to fulfill my OCD

        //set days
        CheckBox check1 = (CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.monbox);    //recreate checkboxes from view in activity (doesnt extend Activity 
        CheckBox check2 = (CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tuebox);    //so use getActivity())
        CheckBox check3 = (CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.wedbox);
        CheckBox check4 = (CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.thubox);
        CheckBox check5 = (CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fribox);
        CheckBox check6 = (CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.satbox);
        CheckBox check7 = (CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sunbox);
        CheckBox vibratebox = (CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.vibratecheckbox);

        if (days[0])
            check1.setChecked(true);            //enable checkboxes to correct bool value
        if (days[1])
            check2.setChecked(true);
        if (days[2])
            check3.setChecked(true);
        if (days[3])
            check4.setChecked(true);
        if (days[4])
            check5.setChecked(true);
        if (days[5])
            check6.setChecked(true);
        if (days[6])
            check7.setChecked(true);
        if (vibrate)
            vibratebox.setChecked(true);

        //set times
        TimePicker startpicker = (TimePicker)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.starttimepicker);
        TimePicker stoppicker = (TimePicker)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.stoptimepicker);

        startpicker.setCurrentHour(times[0]);
        startpicker.setCurrentMinute(times[1]);
        stoppicker.setCurrentHour(times[2]);
        stoppicker.setCurrentMinute(times[3]);

    }



    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        // Save the current article selection in case we need to recreate the fragment
        outState.putInt(ARG_POSITION, mCurrentPosition);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure class `InfoFragment` has public default constructor

```
public class InfoFragment extends Fragment {

    public InfoFragment()
    {
        // Do some stuff
    }

    public InfoFragment(MenuItem add)
    {
       menuItemAddInfo = add;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note to the OP - this will probably result in data loss/NPEs since when the system remakes the Fragment, `add` won't be repassed.

Comment: @A--C I Agree with you. `setRetainInstance()` might help and/or save data when `onSaveInstanceState()` invoked by system.

Comment: `MenuItems` don't serialize. I would try making an interface in the Fragment, implemented by the main Activity. That way, the Fragment can request the `MenuItem` from the Activity when needed.